# Restricting public access of server

Tags: security, nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 2 servers which I run as front-end and back-end server. I use rest api for calls and nginx as reverse proxy in both servers.

I want to restrict public access of back-end server (direct access), and allow access only to front-end server for api calls. Both servers have unique domain. By default if someone tries to get the url of backend server and opens, It should show some error 400 message.

I tried nginx deny and allow but not working.

What may be the best way to do this ?

Comment: if the front-end server is on a static IP, you can just use a firewall. otherwise, you need some sort of authentication or API tokens.

Comment: @root ok i will try firewall and yes both servers have static ip, for now i have done $host != mydomain in nginx server block, is this a good idea ?